# How to calculate total size of all css,js and html pages separately uing shell script?

Tags: css, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following code in shell script

```
find -name "*.css" -exec -printf '%16f Size: %6s\n'
```

This gives me the file size of every css file. How do I modify this to get the added sum of all the file sizes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
find . -name "*.css" -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{ tot+=$0 } END { print tot }'
```

Or in pure `bash`:

```
total=0
while read -r s; 
do 
  total=$(( total+s ))
done < <(find . -name "*.css" -type f -printf '%s\n')

echo $total
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2 steps:

1) ll *css | tr -s " " > filename.txt
2)  awk 'BEGIN {x=0} {x+=$5} END {print x}' filename.txt